# What does the following mean for sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does the following mean in terms of sets? Can someone explain this in words?

$$\{x \mid I \vDash \varphi(x)\}$$

where $I$ is an interpretation

Answer (score 2):

All $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ is true in this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

$\{x \mid I \vDash \varphi(x)\}\;\;$ is the *set* of all $\;x\;$ such that $\;\varphi(x)\;$ is *true* in the given *interpretation* $I$.